# C++ regex string literal with capturing group

Tags: c++, regex

I have a std::string containing backslashes, double quotes. I want to extract a substring using capture group, but I am not able to get the syntax right.
e.g.

```
std::string str(R"(some\"string"name":"john"\"lastname":"doe")");  //==> want to extract "john"
std::regex re(R"(some\"string"name":")"(.*)R"("\"lastname":"doe")");    //==> wrong syntax

std::smatch match;
std::string name;
if (std::regex_search(str, match, re) && match.size() > 1)
{
    name = match.str(1);
}
```

Comment: Do not parse JSON with regular expressions. Parse JSON with a JSON parser....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use a delimeter that does not occur in the string. E.g. `R"~( .... )~"`
2. You still need to escape the `\` for regex. To match `\` literally use `\\`.
3. You probably want to stop as soon as the shortest possible match is found. So use `(.*?)`:

   ```
   std::regex re(R"~(some\\"string"name":"(.*?)"\\"lastname":"doe")~");
   ```

Comment: What is the `R"..."` syntax? Is it necessary?

Comment: `R"..."` is the new literal string syntax. Without it "\\" would need to become "\\\\" :(

Comment: So the unique delimiter is required only in the `std::regex re` or in the `std::string str` too? Or wherever `R` is used?

Comment: @ontherocks Wherever `R` is used.